# Python: why my code does not have output?

Tags: python

Trying to solve leetcode 217 using python:

```
from typing import List

nums = [1,2,3,1]

def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    hashset = set()

    for n in nums:
        if n in hashset:
            return True
        hashset.add(n)
    return False
```

I supposed to get "False" or "True" from the output window, anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: You can simply do `return len(nums) > len(set(nums))`

Comment: Good question, if I put containsDuplicate at the end, and run it again, still no output, I might be too stupid

Comment: A function whose parameters begin with `self` should be a class method. Shouldn't this be inside `class Solution:`?

Comment: Then you'll need to use `print(Solution().containsDuplicate(nums))`

Comment: @Barmar, I guess I can do that, but from sample point of view, I want to make my code work first and will try you method very soon.

Comment: If it's not in a class, you need to remove `self`. Then call `print(containsDuplicate(nums))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Comment: @Barmar, I had removed the class:Solution and self, now I can see the output after call the function:from typing import List

nums = [1,2,3,1]

def containsDuplicate(nums) -> bool:
        hashset = set()

        for n in nums:
            if n in hashset:
                return True
            hashset.add(n)
        return False

print(containsDuplicate(nums))